# How to style jquery chosen select box

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I am using `jQuery` chosen for my `multi-select` box. However, I do find the styles pre-defined in `chosen.css` file is kind of hard to overwrite, which totally getting rid of `chosen.css` might also not be a very good option.

Here is my fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/k1Lr0342/

HTML:

```
<select class="chosen" multiple="true" style="height: 34px; width: 280px">
  <option>Choose...</option>
  <option>jQuery</option>
  <option selected="selected">MooTools</option>
  <option>Prototype</option>
  <option selected="selected">Dojo Toolkit</option>
</select>
```

css:

```
.chosen-choices {
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: none;
    height: 34px !important;
    cursor: text;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 285px;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
```

I tried to directly write the css for `.chosen-choices` `ul`. Some works like `border-radius` and `box-shadow`. But others: `margin, height, padding, border`, etc. get overwritten by `chosen.css` file. One option is to put `!important` for every setting which doesn't work. This will work for most stuffs but still not the height. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you should include your new css below chosen.css will solve your issue. Have you tried that?

Comment: @ketan I tried that. It doesn't seem to work though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[CSS will accept style that uses more specified selector.](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

```
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices {
    /*blah blah*/
}

.chosen-choices {
    /* less specificity, this style might not work  */
}
```

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1Lr0342/1/)**

Comment: You can increase specificity by simply repeating the class selector, like so: `.chosen-choices.chosen-choices`

Answer (score 2):

Try using jQuery, here is the working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/k1Lr0342/)

```
$(".chosen-choices li").css("background","red");
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late but I thought I'd answer since I ran into this.  Since the chosen items you see are based on the select menu it hides, you have to find the element in the div immediately following it (created by chosen) and style it.  You can do this with Jquery assuming you know it's value.

```js
$('.your-select-menu').next().find('.search-choice').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() === someValue) {
    $(this).css("border-color", "#00b300");
  }
})
```

Results in this 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to use:

```
$(".chzn-results li").css("width", "100%");
```

not sure if it's because I have a really old version or what.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested this is some sass I worked out that will style the chosen select box, the biggest issue is it uses background as opposed to background-colour which is why it ignores your css colours`.chosen-drop
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px

&.chosen-results li.result-selected
display: none !important

.chosen-select option
display: none

.chosen-container
width: 100% !important

.chosen-choices
padding: 5px !important
background: $inputBackground !important

li.search-choice
color: $text !important
background: $alternateBackground !important
border-radius: 10px !important

```
span
  padding: 10px`
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at `.chosen-choices` in chosen.css, you will find the height is `auto!important`. Delete (or comment) those `!important` and that should be fine.

You can use your browser's element inspector to check the applied css. I personally use Chrome developer tools every time. Save me alot of hassle

Comment: The thing is I don't want to modify chosen.css